# Java stops working when running a JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am working on a project in which I use `civil` library for capturing image from webcam. There are some JAR and DLL files which I have put in a folder named `lib`.

When I am running the project from NetBeans, it runs fine from there, but when I create and run the jar file by double-clicking it, it gives `Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working` error. But when I remove the DLL files used for `civil` library then JAR file runs fine with no errors.

Can anyone kindly tell what is the reason and solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check, double-check and then triple-check that all classpath settings are good.

Comment: if you run the jar from the command-line you might see some exception trace. That could be useful to understand the problem.

Comment: I suspect there is a bug in your DLLs which don't appear when you remove them.

Comment: Yes @Waqas Ilyas I ran jar from command-line and got this exception "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform", this exception was coming before as well when I was running from NetBeans then I installed 32-bit JDK and problem was solved. Now how can I give path of that 32-bit JDK in jar file (because I have both 32 & 64 bit JDKs installed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a way to specify in the JAR file which JRE should be used. But if you do not use the 64-bit JRE then uninstalling it will solve your problem.

At any given time only one of the JRE versions could be used depending on what *.jar files are associated with on your system. So maybe it is not possible to reliably use both 32-bit and 64-bit JREs on the same machine.

> **Edit 1:**
>
> Have a look at these resources to find out what your options are:
>
> - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html
> - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html
>
> You can create a shortcut for launching your application that runs the target which is similar to this: `"java -jar file.jar -d32"` to enforce that a 32-bit JRE is used if available on the system.